# Picking data from the wrong worksheet

Tags: selection, worksheet

The following code works as planned except that the data is from the "Calendar" worksheet, not the "Booking Details" sheet. Both sheets are in the same workbook.

```
Sub Create_Email_Details()

' Create list showing when to email visitor instructions to guests

Dim iFirst As Integer
Dim iLast As Integer

Sheets("Booking Details").Activate

iFirst = 4                                       ' This is the first row below the headers etc.
iLast = 24

' Print info to pdf

Range("O" & iFirst & ":P" & iLast).PrintOut , ActivePrinter:="Microsoft print to PDF",PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:="C:\users\David\Desktop\Email Dates.pdf"

'Return to default printer
Application.ActivePrinter = "NPI649D87 (HP Color LaserJet M255dw) on Ne00:"

Sheets("Calendar").Activate                     ' Go back to the Calendar tab

End Sub
```

If I take out the Sheets("Calendar").Activate line, I can see the correct area on the Booking Details sheets highlighted as expected.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If I add "Worksheets(2)." in front of the "range("O"...." it works OK.

Comment: So why does the Worksheet Activate command not direct instruction to the correct worksheet?